# Poincaré Duality of a quasi-free algebra

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, duality, hochschild-cohomology, hochschild-homology

I'm completely stumped on this one (yet I feel it is obviously true or obviously false)

If $A$ is a quasi-free algebra, then must it satisfy Poincaré duality?

All i need to find is a protective resolution of finite length, populated entirely by finite dimensional $A^e$-modules, but i do say I haven't made any progress.. so I'm here asking my peers for help on this one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by quasi-free? What exactly do you mean by «satisfy Poincaré duality»?

Comment: I assumed he means Van Der Bergh duality?